# How to generate values from my business logic to the log file using decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, aop, python-decorators

I want to generate values from my business logic in the log file but I am not sure how to go about it.

```
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='new_example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('Please check')

def log_check(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        logging.info(func.__name__ + "took" + str ((end - start) * 1000) + "mili seconds")
        #logging.info('this is what {}'.format(func.__name__)+ func["user"] + " : " + func["passw"])
        print (func.__name__ + "took" + str ((end - start) * 1000) + "mili seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper()

@log_check
def login():
    user = raw_input("Username: ")
    passw = raw_input("Password: ")
    return {"user":user, "passw":passw}
```

I want the values  that I give for user and password to get generated  in the logfile.
how do I do that?
I am getting `INFO:root:logintook1964.99991417mili seconds` as my record in my log file, but I want the values that I enter as the user and password to be generated along with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `result["user"]` and `result["passw"]` instead of `func["user"]` and `func["passw"]`, because the values are in the return value of the function, not in the function itself:

```
def log_check(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        logging.info(func.__name__ + "took" + str ((end - start) * 1000) + "mili seconds")
        logging.info('this is what {}'.format(func.__name__)+ result["user"] + " : " + result["passw"])
        print (func.__name__ + "took" + str ((end - start) * 1000) + "mili seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper()
```

Comment: This will only work for the `login` function - use this decorator on anything not returning a dict with "user" and "passwd" keys and it will crash. Makes the use of a decorator kind of useless, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a generic decorator working if it assumes anything about the decorated function return value - all you can do here is to log the result (whatever it is), ie:

```
def log_check(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        # proper use of `logger` methods: dont build the whole string, just 
        # pass a format string and the matching arguments)
        logging.info("%s took %s milliseconds", func.__name__,  (end - start) * 1000)
        # if you hope to use this decorator on anything else than
        # your login function, don't assume _anything_ about what
        # the decorated func might return
        logging.info('func %s returned %s', func.__name__, result)
        return result


    # You want to return the wrapper function, not
    # to call it !!!
    # return wrapper()
    return wrapper
```

This being said, you shouldn't mix unrelated concerns, ie exploitation data (timeing function execution) and domain specific data (what the function returned etc). I'd personnally do the domain-specific logging from within the function itself instead. And I would **NEVER** log sensitive data like username/password pairs (please remind me to never use one of your programs if that's an habit of yours to leak such things).